# Realization of a subgroup in a maximal subgroup of a classical group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups, embeddings, classical-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\Sp{Sp}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$In the finite group $G = \operatorname{PGL}_8(5)$, there is an elementary abelian $2$-subgroup $E$ of rank 5. $E = A_{1} \times A_{2} $ where $A_{1}$ has rank $2$ and $A_{2}$ rank $3$. Direct computation shows that $C_{G}(E) \cong A_{1} \times (5-1)^3$ and  $N_{G}(E)/C_{G}(E) \cong \begin{pmatrix}
\Sp_{2}(2) & 0 \\ 
*_{3\times2} & S_{4}   
\end{pmatrix}.$ It's obvious that $\Sp_{2}(2)$ acts on $A_{1}$ and $S_{4}$ on $(5-1)^3$.

I believe this $A_{2}$ corresponds to a maximal elementary abelian $2$-subgroup $EK$ contained in a maximal torus of $K = \operatorname{PGL}_{4}(\mathbb{C})$ with centraliser $T_{3}$ and $N_{K}(EK)/C_{K}(EK)$ isomorphic to $S_{4}$. Hence we have $S_{4}$ acting on $(5-1)^3$ in the finite group.

What's interesting is that computation shows that $E$ has a $G$-conjugate $E'$ contained in a Class $2$ maximal subgroup $M = \SL_{2}(5)^4.(5-1)^3.S_{4}$ of $G$. Let's identify $E$ with $E'$. And direct computation shows that $N_{G}(E)$ can be realized in this $M$. I suppose $A_{1}.\Sp_{2}(2)$ is embedded in the $\SL_{2}(5)^4$ part since $\SL_{2}(5)$ has a quaternion subgroup. I can't see how $*_{3\times2}$ is realized in this $M$. And this has the potential to be generalized to $\operatorname{PGL}_{n}$ where n is even.

Comment: I know the notation, e.g., $4^3$, but what does $(5 - 1)^3$ mean?

Comment: Sorry. It does mean $4^{3}$. I put it this way because it comes from $(q-1)^3$. Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to define the subgroup $E$ more precisely, perhaps by giving generating matrices in ${\rm GL}(8,5)$.

Comment: I think you have understated $M$. The normalizer of one of your $SL_2(5)$'s in $M$ induces all of $PGL_2(5)$ on that $SL_2(5)$.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I thought not many interested. Do you mean like: $N_{G}(SL_{2}(5))$ induces all of $PGL_{2}(5)$? Would you please elaborate more? Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, my comment was not germane. Let $M_0$ be the $SL_2(5)^4$ subgroup of your $M$. Let $H=H_1\times H_2\times H_3\times H_4$ where each $H_i\cong SL_2(5)$. Write $Z(H_i)=<z_i>$, $1\le i\le 4$, and let $z=z_1z_2z_3z_4$. Then there is an exact sequence $1\to\langle z\rangle\to H\to M_0\to 1$. Also let $Q_i$ be a quaternion $8$-subgroup of $H_i$ and let $Q\cong Q_8$ be a "diagonal" subgroup of $Q^*:=Q_1\times Q_2\times Q_3\times Q_4$, i.e., the projection of $Q$ on each $H_i$ is $Q_i$. Then let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be the images of $Q$ and $Z(H)$ in $M_0$. (continued)

Comment: Your $E$ is then $A_1\times A_2$, and you can find elements of $N_{M_0}(E)$ inducing your $*_{3\times 2}$ in the image of $Q^*$ in $M_0$.

Comment: @Richard Lyons  Thank you very much!

Comment: @RichardLyons  Sorry to trouble with a further question. I computed $N_{M_0}(E)/C_{M_0}(E)$ with |$N_{M_0}(E)$| = 6144 and |$C_{M_0}(E)$| = 32. I found it was $2^6.3$. This $3$ in the end confused me as I thought it should be $Sp_{2}(2)$... Where did I drop that $2$?  Thank you!

Comment: @user488802: I think the extra 2 is not in $N_{M_0}(E)/C_{M_0}(E)$, but it can be found in $N_M(E)/C_M(E)$, inducing non-inner automorphisms on each $H_i$.